# Username and email live validation with jquery in rails 6

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to incorporate client side validation for username and email on my registration forms.  I found client_side_validations but all the information I amfindint of for rails 5 and before.  Is there something that works with rails 6 or if clicnt_side_validations, can someone give me some idesas on how to make it work for rails 6.

I instlled the gem and rand the rails g client_side_validations:install. it said it would install2 files, one of which would need to be included in the application.html.erb page but that file was not createdwhen I ranit.

I'm new to rails and haven't done any jquery in rails so I'm really lost.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you didn't bundled it? Didn't add to the Gemfile, but only install it (gem install...)?

You might grab those files at the github [js-files](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations/tree/master/dist), find [initializer](https://github.com/DavyJonesLocker/client_side_validations/tree/master/lib/generators/templates/client_side_validations) but it won't run properly without installed gem.

Also, don't worry about rails 5/6 right now. Until you experience the error, there's nothing to worry about. When you see the error, you can always post to StackOverflow.

Comment: I followed the instructions exactly. I added the g and ran the command to create the 2 files.  The one file is supposed to go into a folder I do not have, public/javascripts. I can create the folder but didn't know if it would work because of the differences between the versions.

Comment: The problem is that public/javascripts is the webpacker format, while you use non-webpacker tutorial. You can either learn webpacker (it's a lot of "fun" :) ) or you can avoid using webpacker and still have javascripts compiled "old-way".You'll have to learn another tutorial to switch to old non-webpacker version.